# winforms Tooltip in winforms DataGridViewImageColumn

Tags: image, datagridview, tooltip, winforms

I have the following code that successfully displays an image in its column based on its bound DataProperty:

```
  private void dgvTasks_CellFormatting( object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e ) {
        if (dgvTasks.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewImageColumn && e.ColumnIndex == 1) {
            e.Value = ( (bool)e.Value == true ) ? Properties.Resources.ok : Properties.Resources.clock;
        }
  }
```

but I would like to know how its possible to show a tooltip when a user hovers over the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

generally if you have row & column for a cell, you can set a ToolTipText using:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].ToolTipText = "..."
```

and in your case, you have e.RowIndex and e.RowIndex:

```
dgvTasks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ToolTipText = "..."
```

Comment: woa..that was quick
U R A STAR!!! thank u much!  dont know why i didnt think of that?  anyway, now that I have that, I can work out the logic to determine the tooltiptext. Thanks again.